implement (callback) server with k6
I would like to test PKCE flow in K6 without real web application. Instead, I need a fake application that would act as a web application. Is it possible to do it with K6 somehow?  any library that I can use with k6?
I'm starting my test in a form of k8s job so maybe in the worst case I could just spin off a container with callback server.

What exactly are you trying to test with k6?

k6 only simulates clients (outgoing requests), it is not able to simulate an HTTP server (incoming requests).
But if you need a server application to implement the full flow, it doesn't make a lot of sense to perform the test without the application. I would suggest creating a small dummy service and then executing your k6 script against that dummy service. The dummy service can then redirect the clients to your auth server.
